# How can I redirect to another view-model in Aurelia JS?

Tags: aurelia

I'm writing an application using [Aurelia JS](http://aurelia.io/). How can I redirect to another URL? Is there a way to do it without creating a whole new [navigation pipeline step](http://aurelia.io/docs.html#customizing-the-navigation-pipeline)?

Thanks

Comment: Depending on your use case, I believe the `canActivate` method can return a route instruction object, like this: `{ redirect: '#/someRoute' }`

Comment: Thanks. This is outside of canActivate.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

to do that inject the router in the ViewModel and use the method [navigate(route)](https://github.com/aurelia/router/blob/master/src/router.js#L69)

here is an example:

```
import {Router} from 'aurelia-router';

export class MyVM {

  static inject() { return [Router]; }

  constructor(router){
    this.router = router;
  }

  someMethod(){
    this.router.navigate("myroute");
  }
}
```

Comment: this.storage is definetly not needed (copy-paste from some of my code) 

i just tested it without the hash and it seems to work but generating a slightly different hash in the url... "/myroute" gives you http://mydomain/#myurl while "#/myroute" generates http://mydomain/#/myurl

but i think there is no need for the '/' at the beginning so i'm removing it from the code :)

Comment: @DanielCamarda Hi Daniel, is the exception thrown when calling it 'router' a bug? I was experiencing the same thing and it was driving me mad. EDIT: Just spotted the post below by Rob.

Comment: yeah :) just edited the answer to add @EisenbergEffect reference to the bug

Comment: @SunjayVarma "The this.storage line probably shouldn't be there. " This is confusing. For me I needed a this.<localname> for the router to be accessible to the class methods.

Comment: @KevinM I deleted that comment. It was in reference to some code that was there which Daniel then edited out.

Comment: In the latest version this method is changed to `navigateToRoute`.

Answer (score 21):

Just thought I'd update @Daniel Camarda's excellent answer a little. As of Feb 2016 you can use Aurelia's `inject` decorator. Also, the `router` naming issue has been resolved.

```
import {inject} from 'aurelia-framework';
import {Router} from 'aurelia-router';


@inject(Router)
export class MyVM {

  constructor(router){
    this.router = router;
  }

  someMethod(){
    this.router.navigate("myroute");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 17):

Quick bit of related info: The naming issue with "router" is something we are tracking here: https://github.com/aurelia/router/issues/34  If you are reading this answer later, and this issue has been closed, then you should be able to safely  name your property "router" if you so choose.

Comment: To save anyone checking, @EisenbergEffect closed this issue March 2015.

Answer (score 8):

*Perhaps a slightly different use-case, but posting since it's so similar:* Upon entering a view, based on e.g. parameters, I want to redirect to a different view. This must happen in `activate()` or `canActivate()`.

*In this case*, both navigate() and navigateToRoute() suggested above does not work.

What does work however is `return new Redirect('....')` where Redirect is imported from aurelia-router, like this:

```
canActivate(param) {
    if (param.id == null)
        return new Redirect('/viewWhichDoesntNeedParam')
}
```